# How can i get lists of id in <list> after insert in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, webforms

I have 3 Tables with relationship like this:

[image]

I'm using LINQ to insert to SQL. I can get **Customer_Id** after insert to Customer table and insert to **Customer_OrderTour** table. But with lists of **Id_visitors** in **List_Visitors** table how can i get them and insert to **Customer_OrderTour** table (because relationship of **Customer_OrderTour** and **List_Visitors** is many-to-many).

Here is my code:

```
int customer_id = 0;

#region [Add List Visitors]
private void AddListVisitors(StringCollection sc)
{
        List_Visitor add_visitors = new List_Visitor();
        var listsToAdd = new List<List_Visitor>();
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {
            if (item.Contains(","))
            {
                var splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());

                listsToAdd.Add(new List_Visitor() { 
                    Fullname = splitItems[0],
                    add = splitItems[1],
                    Sex = splitItems[2]
                });
            }
        }
        using (var db = new Travel_DBDataContext())
        {
            db.List_Visitors.InsertAllOnSubmit(listsToAdd);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        } 
}
#endregion

#region [Get List Visitors]
private void GetListVisitors() {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox visitor_txtName = (TextBox)grdListVisitors.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtName");
                    TextBox visitor_txtAdd = (TextBox)grdListVisitors.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtAdd");
                    DropDownList visitor_ddlSex = (DropDownList)grdListVisitors.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("ddlSex");

                    sc.Add(visitor_txtName.Text + "," + visitor_txtAdd.Text + "," + visitor_ddlSex.SelectedItem.Text);
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                //Store the current data to StringCollection
                AddListVisitors(sc);        
}
#endregion

#region [Add New Customer]
private void AddNewCustomer() {
        Customer add_customer = new Customer();
        add_customer.Fullname = txtName.Text;
        add_customer.add = txtAdd.Text;
        add_customer.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
        add_customer.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(add_customer);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        customer_id = add_customer.Customer_Id;
}
#endregion

#region [Add Customer Order]
private void AddCustomerOrder (){
    Customer_OrderTour cus_order = new Customer_OrderTour();
    cus_order.Customer_Id = customer_id;
    cus_order.Id_visitors = //What should I do here?
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a link or join table if they're many to many? Maybe I'm missing something but you should get the Id from Customer_OrderTour and insert that into a new table 'Tour_Visitors' that also has the ids of all rows inserted into List_Vistors.

Comment: Well you need to create the new DB table and then regenerate your DBML. I'd also suggest seperating your code out into something closer to an n-tier structure, just cause it's going to get messy if this is expanding into something larger.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton because my project is small. I don't know how to get list Id_visitors. Give me some advices. Thank you :)

Comment: Ok, what you're going to need to do is loop through the list of visitors and add each one to the database, get the Id of the newly added row and insert that + the customer_ordertourid into the new join table. That way you end up with your link table populated with the relevant data. Have a read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton that's my idea. But i don't know how to use loop through the list of visitors and add each one to the database. Can you edit my code. Thank you so much